# In George Méliès' Cinderella, what are the dancing clocks supposed to be?

Tags: cinderella-1899

In George Méliès' 1899 adaptation of Cinderella, the titular woman returns home after the ball, clearly distraught. Then a clock starts to move, people emerge from it, and then they dance.

Then suddenly everything is back to normal and the prince arrives.

What exactly are these dancing clocks supposed to be? Are they some sort of supernatural being like the fairy godmother? Or is this the 1899 version of a trippy dream sequence?

Comment: You're more than welcome to add your support for diacritics in tags here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270362/why-are-diacritics-not-supported-in-tags-consistently Though I doubt SE will see we have enough need for it... not in the way that a French language site would, for example.